# Centering of Kendo Grid after Populating Grid

Tags: javascript, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid that, upon the activation of the event listeners below, opens up in the center of the Web page. However, it centers based upon how filled the grid is, and before the grid is populated with rows of data, it of course has 0 rows. I need the grid to center on the screen AFTER the kendo grid has been populated, not BEFORE as it's currently doing. Any insight on this? Thanks.

```
studentSearchWindow = $("#studentSearchWindow").kendoWindow({
    visible: false,
    resizable: false,
    minWidth: "540px",
    maxWidth: "630px",
    modal: true
}).data("kendoWindow");

windowSearchResultsGrid = createWindowSearchResultsGrid();

$("#masterMagnifyingGlass").on("click", function () {
    refreshWindowSearchResultsGrid();
    studentSearchWindow.center();
    studentSearchWindow.open();
});

$("#masterSearchBox").on("keydown", function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        refreshWindowSearchResultsGrid();
        studentSearchWindow.center();
        studentSearchWindow.open();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```